# Geometric series of $\frac{1}{1+3e^{i\,t}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

What's the geometric sum equivalent to the rational expression shown below? $$\frac{1}{  1+3e^{i\,t}},\quad t\in\mathbb{R^+}$$

I've been trying for so long, and Wolfram|Mathematica won't help me either.

Comment: The conditions $x\ge0$ and $x=e^{it}$ are somewhat in conflict....

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I'm a bit tired. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$\frac{1}{1+3e^{it}}=\frac{1}{3e^{it}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3e^{it}}}$$

Then, we have

$$\frac{1}{1+3e^{it}}=\frac{1}{3e^{it}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-3e^{it}\right)^{-n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^ne^{-int}$$

Comment: How does the first equal sign hold true? If we divide the LHS with 9, to get $x/3$, then our term becomes $\frac{1/9}{1/9+x/3}$? What am I missing

Comment: @B.Lee I just returned from a medical procedure and apparently am affected by the treatment.  You didn't miss anything.  I posted an incorrect answer.

Comment: Hope it's nothing serious. You should know this helped me a lot. I'm not too keen on spotting patterns and so I tend to go by memory; this means I often miss these *tricks*. Just wanted to thank you, even though I got the impression it's frowned upon.

Comment: @B.Lee Well, the acute problem might or might not be serious.  The chronic issue has no cure; am happy to discuss off line.  I'm very pleased to hear that the answer was able to help!!  And you're very welcome.  It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

For $|x| \lt 1$ it holds that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$, and therefore $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-3x)^k = \frac{1}{1+3x}$ (if $|x| \lt \frac13$).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** You have, for $|z|<\dfrac13$,

> $$
> \frac{1}{  1+3z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n3^n z^n
> $$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{1}{1+3x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-3)^nx^n \quad |x|<\frac13.
$$